# Codeigniter and 123reg .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, hosting

My site worked fine on my other hosting but now I have uploaded this to 123reg hosting my rewrite URLs no longer work. This is my htaccess file. The home page displays but every other page doesn't load properly, just shows the home page.

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|fonts|data|css|uploaded|mobile_devices|audioplayer|emails|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is that you are hosted on a setup which provides you with PHP implemented as CGI or FastCGI.

You could try this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|fonts|data|css|uploaded|mobile_devices|audioplayer|emails|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And you should remember to edit your `application/config/config.php` file. Specifically, change:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

To:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

The reason is that CGI/FCGI doesn't provide PHP with the PATH_INFO variable, which makes it neccesary to send the info as the query string to CI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this RewriteCond is a non-sense:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|fonts|data|css|uploaded|mobile_devices|audioplayer|emails|robots\.txt)
```

Because the first argument mut be something that exists i.e.:

see [mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

- %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}
- %{HTTP_REFERER}
- %{HTTP_COOKIE}
- %{HTTP_FORWARDED}

...

- %{HTTPS}

The `$1` relates to something that should have been pre-calculated: see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#InternalBackRefs) for more information:

> Using parentheses in Pattern or in one of the CondPatterns causes
>   back-references to be internally created. These can later be
>   referenced using the strings $N and %N (see below), for creating the
>   Substitution and TestString strings.

You may have forgotten something in your question, or (worse) some rewrite rules from your previous provider.